# SQL Repeated Outer Join Improving Efficiency

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

**Probelm Statement:**

> Write a query to return 2015 sales information for each supplier.  We would like to include all suppliers in the result set, regardless of whether their products were sold in 2015.
>
> Sales are determined using Sales.Orders and Sales.OrderLines as in the previous two questions. However, since we are asking for this information from the perspective of the supplier, you also need to use the tables Warehouse.StockItems and Purchasing.Suppliers.
>
> The columns required in the result set are:
>
> **SupplierID** - As it appears in the table Purchasing.Suppliers.
>   **SupplierName** - As it appears in the table Purchasing.Suppliers.
>   **OrderCount** - The number of orders placed on products for each supplier.
>   **Sales** - The subtotal from the orders placed, calculated from Quantity and UnitPrice of the table Sales.OrderLines.
>
> The results should be sorted such that the supplier with the highest sales is at the top.  If two suppliers have the same sales, next use the order count with the highest count at the top.  If two suppliers have the same sales and order count, use the supplier name in ascending order as the final tie breaker. This will ensure a deterministic result.

I am using the `WorldWideImporters` Microsoft sample database tables. I am trying to return the `2015 sales information` for each supplier in `Purchasing.Suppliers`. I am returning the `OrderCount` and the `Sum of the 2015 sales` in respective columns. I am having trouble with `joins` here since I have to connect `Suppliers` to the `Warehouse.StockItems` and then connect these items to specific `OrderLines` which have a field for `StockItemID`.

The problem is that usually I would join `orders` to `orderlines`, so that I could filter only `orders` and thus `orderlines` in `2015`. However, with the table structure that I have specified, it seems I have to connect `OrderLines` to `Orders`.

So what I did was to `join` those `Orders` back with `OrderLines` to provide the result I am used to. Here is my attempt at a solution:

```
<pre>
SELECT S.SupplierID
      ,S.SupplierName
      ,COUNT(DISTINCT O.OrderID) AS OrderCount
      ,ISNULL(SUM(OLP.Quantity * OLP.UnitPrice), 0.00) AS Sales
FROM Purchasing.Suppliers AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS W ON S.SupplierID = W.SupplierID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS OL ON W.StockItemID = OL.StockItemID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.Orders AS O ON OL.OrderID = O.OrderID
                                  AND O.OrderDate BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31'
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS OLP ON O.OrderID = OLP.OrderID
GROUP BY S.SupplierID
        ,S.SupplierName
ORDER BY Sales DESC
        ,OrderCount
        ,SupplierName;
</pre>
```

**Edit:**

Results:
Look to have every `supplier` as expected even ones that had no `sales` or `orders`. I am not sure if the calculated `sales` is correct though and I am not sure how to verify. Didn't know if anyone saw a flaw in my query.

I have no idea if this is correct or the most efficient way to solve this problem. I do have constraints that I can only use `joins`, no `subqueries`, `unions`, etc.

Any help in understanding would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should mark each column with the source table.

Comment: Please read & act on [mcve]. Show that your program calculates what you expect it to as it goes through (sub)expressions--including that arguments passed to each function/operator meet its requirements--by saying what that is & showing that it actually does it via incremental output. Part of finding a MCVE is finding a maximal working example for partial functionality. Ask about the (small) difference between the examples. Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexhange homework'. PS How is "join orders to orderlines" different from "connect OrderLines to Orders"?

Comment: Please put a link you are using in your question. But also please make your post self-contained, include DDL, example input & desired output, etc. Links die. PS You aren't clear re how umatched rows affect the result. We can't deduce from your query  because you don't say it's correct. Of course, we can guess. But being able to express this clearly is part of programming the solution & giving a [mcve]. Also, [what does "efficient" mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204461) Also see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097).

Comment: Hi. Learn what LEFT JOIN returns: INNER JOIN rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by NULLs. Always know what INNER JOIN you want as part of a LEFT JOIN. A WHERE or ON that requires a right table column to be not NULL after a LEFT JOIN, which you have, removes any rows extended by NULLs, ie leaves only INNER JOIN rows, ie "turns LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN".

Comment: @philipxy I have updated my question. I am new to this both SQL and this forum so please give me feedback. Thank you

Comment: If you want to be able to answer such questions, you must learn to take such a meandering specification & find the test/condition (*(characteristic) predicate*) of the result (& each base table) per my comment on the current answer. If you just post a specification (either style) you are just asking us to do your homework. If you want a *justified* answer then you expect a tutorial & if *tested* for us to find & type data. Please act on my other comments. Especially MCVE & homework (show & justify parts you can do). That's lots of feedback already.

Answer (score 0):

To benchmark the orders, without regard to suppliers or order lines:

```
/* query 1 */
SELECT 
       COUNT(*)         AS ordercount
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20150101' AND o.OrderDate < '20160101'
```

Then to benchmark the orders lines, without regard to suppliers:

```
/* query 2 */
SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)         AS ordercount
     , SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice) AS sales
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20150101' AND o.OrderDate < '20160101'
```

Now start introducing more joins, and if the values alter then the most recent join is at fault:

```
/* query 3 */
SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)         AS ordercount
     , SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice) AS sales
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS w ON w.StockItemID = olp.StockItemID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20150101' AND o.OrderDate < '20160101'
```

and then:

```
/* query 4 */
SELECT
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)         AS ordercount
     , SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice) AS sales
FROM Sales.Orders AS o
        INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS w ON w.StockItemID = olp.StockItemID
        INNER JOIN Purchasing.Suppliers s ON s.SupplierID = w.SupplierID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20150101' AND o.OrderDate < '20160101'
```

You certainly don't need to join order lines twice, regarding the left joins it depends on what it is you are trying to achieve, e.g.:

Only suppliers with orders in the date range:

```
/* query 5 */
SELECT
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
  , COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)                       AS ordercount
  , ISNULL(SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice), 0.00) AS sales
FROM Purchasing.Suppliers s
    INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS w ON s.SupplierID = w.SupplierID
    INNER JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON w.StockItemID = olp.StockItemID
    INNER JOIN Sales.Orders AS o ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
WHERE o.OrderDate >= '20150101' 
    AND o.OrderDate < '20160101' -- note: this is "the next" day
GROUP BY
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
ORDER BY
    sales DESC
  , ordercount
  , SupplierName;
```

All suppliers with stock references:

```
/* query 6 */
SELECT
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
  , COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)                       AS ordercount
  , ISNULL(SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice), 0.00) AS sales
FROM Purchasing.Suppliers s
    INNER JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS w ON s.SupplierID = w.SupplierID
    LEFT JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON w.StockItemID = olp.StockItemID
    LEFT JOIN Sales.Orders AS o ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
                                AND o.OrderDate >= '20150101' 
                                AND o.OrderDate < '20160101' -- note: this is "the next" day
GROUP BY
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
ORDER BY
    sales DESC
  , ordercount
  , SupplierName;
```

Every supplier:

```
/* query 7 */
SELECT
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
  , COUNT(DISTINCT o.OrderID)                       AS ordercount
  , ISNULL(SUM(olp.Quantity * olp.UnitPrice), 0.00) AS sales
FROM Purchasing.Suppliers s
    LEFT JOIN Warehouse.StockItems AS w ON s.SupplierID = w.SupplierID
    LEFT JOIN Sales.OrderLines AS olp ON w.StockItemID = olp.StockItemID
    LEFT JOIN Sales.Orders AS o ON olP.OrderID = o.OrderID
                                AND o.OrderDate >= '20150101' 
                                AND o.OrderDate < '20160101' -- note: this is "the next" day
GROUP BY
    s.SupplierID
  , s.SupplierName
ORDER BY
    sales DESC
  , ordercount
  , SupplierName;
```

Please be very cautious about using `between` for date ranges, the most reliable way to define a date range is to use `>=` and `<` as shown above, this way it does not matter what the time precision of the data is. Also YYYYMMDD is the safest date literal format in TSQL.

Comment: Your query does not include the suppliers that have no orders and/or no sales. This is why I did a left join. Also your calculated sales are different from mine, I am not sure which is correct

Comment: @RobWantsToLearn But as I said your question neither clearly explains nor gives an example of desired output. "I am not sure if the calculated sales is correct though and I am not sure how to verify." Find input data for some situation(s) with various cases & work out desired output data by hand and/or queries & post. Describe what you want at least by how you calculated the desired output. The best way is to give a test/condition that says for a given row of  values (supplierid, suppliername, ordercount, sales) whether it appears in the result--in terms of the situation and/or base tables.

Comment: You can introduce `left joins` if you need to list all suppliers, it wasn't clear to me that's what you needed. Regarding the difference in calculation, by joining orderlines twice you have multiplied the rows.

Comment: Your last two queries provides incorrect results, it shows that one company has 0 orders but has a sales amount. The sales are also way too high leading me to believe that it is calculating the total sales over all years. The first inner join query provides more believable results for sales, but does not include the suppliers with null ordercount and sales (as it shouldn't) I am having a hard time getting the correct query figured out.

Comment: Upon further examination it seems that the OrderCount may be wrong. When I total the orders using two different separate queries for orders in 2015 I get 23,329 total orders. With the queries we are doing we are getting 53,292 orders. So it seems we may be querying more than just the 2015 orders.

Comment: It is more likely that the joins are multiplying the results, without access to data i can do no more.

Comment: I added 4 more queries. If you need to discuss any please specify the query by number so I know which one you are talking about. Note, this question may get closed (there are 2 close votes already). Suggestions for future questions:  [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)